# I'm having trouble displaying comments on my Rails Blog

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, blogs, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm currently working on my Rails Blog. While the development is coming along nicely, I've hit a roadblock in the comment.

Every time I try to leave a test comment, I always get "rollback transaction" just before the comment gets saved.
[Here's what happens when I create a comment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnLmF.png)

Here's the code for looking at blog entry:

post/show.html.erb

```
<h1 class="title">
  <%= @post.title %>
</h1>
<h2>Authored by:
  <%= @post.user.username%>
</h2>
<p>
  <%=raw @post.content %>
</p>

<div class="comments">
  <h3 class="is-3">Comments</h3>

  <%if  @post.comments.count == 0%>
    <strong>There are no comments on this post. Feel free to send one!</strong><br/>
    <% else %>
      <%= render @post.comments %>
        <% end %>

          <%if !user_signed_in? %>
            <strong>Yo, if you wanna comment on my site, either <%= link_to 'Sign up',  new_user_registration_path %> or <%= link_to 'Log in',  new_user_session_path %></strong>
            <% else %>
              <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {comment: @post.comments.new} %>
                <% end %>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div class="functions">
    <%= link_to "Update", edit_post_path(@post) if policy(@post).update? do%>
      <i class="fa fa-edit editpage fa-3x"></i>
      <% end %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", @post, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this post?", :method => :delete  if policy(@post).destroy? do%>
          <i class="fa fa-trash deletepage fa-3x"></i>
          <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Back to the main page', root_path %>
```

In case you're curious, here's what the comment partial looks like:

```
<strong><%= @post.comment.user.username %> says:</strong><br>
<%=@post.comment.content %>
  <p>
    <=time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %>
</p>
```

Can anyone help me figure out why is it that when I create a comment, it rolls back the transaction? I'll provide more information if required.

Edit: Here's the Comments Controller for my rails blog.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_post
    def create
        set_post
        # Create associated model, just like we did in the console before
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
        # We want to show the comment in the context of the Post
        @comment.post_id = @post.post_id
        @comment.user_id = current_user.user_id
        @comment.save
        redirect_to @post
    end


    def update
        @comment = set_comment
        @comment.update(comment_params)
        redirect_to @post
    end

    def destroy
        @comment = set_comment
        @comment.destroy
        redirect_to @post
    end

    private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    end

    def set_post
        @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
    end

    def set_comment
        @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Comment Model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Also, the Comment form

```
<strong><%= @post.comment.user.username %> says:</strong><br>
    <%=@post.comment.content %>
    <p><= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %></p>
```

Comment: Can you put the code of your controller?

Comment: Do you have any validations in the model? Could you show the code in the model?

Comment: I don't have validations on the Comment model of any kind.